# Using do.call() to pass arguments from 2 different lists into a function with 2 parameters in R

Tags: r, function, do.call

I have been struggling to implement `do.call()`. I have a function that I have to run many times to generate a series of different plots. Instead of inputting each argument, I want each pair of arguments to be accessed from a table. This seems like it should be possible with do.call() but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is a basic example I made to try to troubleshoot how to accomplish this.

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  z = x + y
  assign(gsub(" ","_",paste("sum of", x, "and", y)), z, env=.GlobalEnv) 
}

list_x = as.list(c(1, 2, 3))
list_y = as.list(c(4, 3, 2))

do.call(fun, c(list_x, list_y))

sum_of_1_and_4
sum_of_2_and_3
sum_of_3_and_2
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (x, y)  : unused arguments (3, 4, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `mapply()` might be a better fit in this situation:

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  z = x + y
  assign(gsub(" ","_",paste("sum of", x, "and", y)), z, env=.GlobalEnv) 
}
list_x = list(1, 2, 3)
list_y = list(4, 3, 2)

mapply(fun, list_x, list_y)
```

Yielding the following output:

```
sum_of_1_and_4
[1] 5
sum_of_2_and_3
[1] 5
sum_of_3_and_2
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a great fit, mapply() worked perfectly for my actual application

Comment: @talker90 no worries, `mapply` is a very useful function for when you have multiple sets of parameters. Great example from a recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874057/10366237).