# Create data frame with replicated blocks of columns, whose characteristics are specified in separate table's rows

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a follow-up to this question: [Create data frame with column characteristics from separate table's rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73873938/8363056)

My real-world problem is a little bit more complicated than specified there.

I have a descriptive, auxiliary table whose rows specify variable's characteristics, where `varCat` describes a variable category, `rept` the number of later-to-implement repetitions of said category (unfortunately in a specific order), and `form` their data format:

```r
library(tibble)
descr <- tibble(
  varCat = c("a", "b_x", "b_y", "c_m", "c_n"),
  rept = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 2),
  form = c("text", "num", "text", "int", "text")
)
descr
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   varCat  rept form 
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 a          1 text 
#> 2 b_x        3 num  
#> 3 b_y        3 text 
#> 4 c_m        2 int  
#> 5 c_n        2 text
```

Note that the first part of a variable category's name specifies a "block", i.e. for instance `b_x` and `b_y` form a block, then `c_m, c_n` form the next.

Each block as a whole should be replicated - the number of times can be read off `rept` -, *before turning to the next block (edited)*.

In reality there are many more blocks of varying size (row numbers), and the respective number of repetitions varies also.

*Edit: Only after the sequence of a given block, the replications of the next block should start.*

Ultimately I'd like to obtain the following (empty) data frame:

```
d
#> # A tibble: 0 × 11
#> # … with 11 variables: a <chr>, b_x_1 <dbl>, b_y_1 <chr>, b_x_2 <dbl>,
#> #   b_y_2 <chr>, b_x_3 <dbl>, b_y_3 <chr>, c_m_1 <int>, c_n_1 <chr>,
#> #   c_m_2 <int>, c_n_2 <chr>
```

Any help in achieving this would be much appreciated!

I suppose a solution cannot simply take `rep(descr$varCat, descr$rept)` as a starting point (unlike the solutions to my earlier, too-simple question), due to the necessity to arrange variables in blocks.

Comment: Do you have other values for `form`

Comment: @akrun Yes, there are integers also; let's say "int"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(data.table)
df1 <- descr %>%
   mutate(form = case_match(form, "text" ~ "c", "num" ~ "d", 
    "int" ~ "i")) %>%
   uncount(rept) %>%
   arrange(rowid(varCat)) %>% 
   mutate(varCat = if(n() > 1) str_c(varCat, '_', row_number()) else 
      varCat, .by = 'varCat') %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = varCat, values_from = form)
nm1 <- cols(!!! df1)
type_convert(df1, col_types = nm1) %>%
   slice(0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 0 × 7
# … with 7 variables: a <chr>, b_x_1 <dbl>, b_y_1 <chr>, b_x_2 <dbl>, b_y_2 <chr>, b_x_3 <dbl>, b_y_3 <chr>
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
 nm1 <- setNames(c("as.character", "as.numeric", "as.integer"), 
     c("text", "num", "int"))[descr$form]
v1 <- with(descr, rep(varCat, rept))
nm1 <- rep(nm1, descr$rept)
v2 <- ave(v1, v1, FUN = function(x) if(length(x) == 1) x 
    else paste0(x, "_", seq_along(x)))
ord1 <-order(ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along)) 
v2 <- v2[ord1]
nm1 <- nm1[ord1]
out <- data.frame(setNames(Map(function(x, y) match.fun(y)(x), 
      seq_along(v2), nm1), v2))[0,]
```

-output

```
> str(out)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ a    : chr 
 $ b_x_1: num 
 $ b_y_1: chr 
 $ b_x_2: num 
 $ b_y_2: chr 
 $ b_x_3: num 
 $ b_y_3: chr 

> out %>% as_tibble
# A tibble: 0 × 7
# … with 7 variables: a <chr>, b_x_1 <dbl>, b_y_1 <chr>, b_x_2 <dbl>, b_y_2 <chr>, b_x_3 <dbl>, b_y_3 <chr>
```

Comment: To my own fault, I wasn't clear enough in my original post on how different blocks should be ordered in the to-be-generated data frame: Only after the repetitions of, say, the `b` block, should the next block start. I have edited the original post accordingly. Can I ask if you could account for that as well...?

Comment: Please allow me one last nudge... Do you think it might work to order the columns in two steps, i.e. use "your" approach of `order(ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along))` within each level of a second index for the blocks as such, generated for instance via `as.numeric(factor(str_extract(v1, ".*(?=_)|^.$")))`?